# Joins in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I create 2 tables courses and students and insert data, when return data from those 2 table (foreign key relation in those tables) it gives me all data but name column is same in students and courses tables, when i display name it shows only course name but i want both student and course name

here is my code for controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('students')
            ->join('courses', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('students.course_id', '=', 'courses.course_id')
                    ->where('courses.course_id', '=', 101);
            })
            ->get();
//        dd($data);
        return view('student.home', compact('data'));
    }
```

display code

```
 @foreach($data as $d)
     {{ $d->roll_no }}
     {{ $d->name }}
     <br>
     @endforeach
```

courses table migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('course_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('credit_hour');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('course_id');
        });
    }
```

students table migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('roll_no');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('course_id');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('roll_no');
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('course_id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

how i display both course name and student name

Comment: at this time it display only course name and all other data from both tables except student name

Comment: It's probably because in both tables you have 2 columns named `name`. Try to rename columns to `student_name` and `course_name`. That should do it.

Comment: any other solution .....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom select to your query builder and rename existing columns to prevent columns being excluded in the results.

Example:

```
DB::table('students')

    ->select(['*', DB::raw('students.name as student_name')])

    ->join(....
```

You can access this property like:

```
@foreach ($data as $d)

    {{ $d->student_name }}

@endforeach
```

Use dd($d) in your foreach and see what attributes you can access now.